# Could I use a cloud virtual machine to program?

Tags: azure, cloud, virtual-machine

So as the question says could I use something like Azure or google compute service, to create a VM and then from there connect to it from a pc anywhere and program on the VM from the pc.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs, that's possible.

You can create a Windows or Linux VM and connect per RDP or SSH to that machine. Then you install your coding environment there. Because the VM in Azure runs on a Hyper Visor not everything is possible. For example if you want to create Windows Phone apps with Visual studio that does not work because that would imply to create a Hyper-V instance inside a Hyper-V instance, which currently does not work.

But that really depends on that what your are coding.

Also take care to stop your VM after working so you have not ongoing cost for your VM. Stop the VM from the Azure management portal, not from inside the VM.

You can even create a virtual network in which you create your VM and in that network you can create other VMs that serve as your development environment in case your working on multi-tier solutions or other server developments.

I think the possibilities are (almost) endless. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

the answer is yes, when you have a VM, you can connect it using RDP, right now, I'm using an Azure VM, there I have VS 2013 and VS2015, and all works fine! Also, for the Aure VM, the internet connection is so fast!

This VM is **your** VM, so you can install or change all that you need!